# Multiple show segue from tableview cell in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue, uitableview

Having a view controller on that I have a `tableView` with some sections. I want a multiple segue from the `tableView` cell. When I am creating a segue from the `tableView` in the storyboard the first segue is created properly but when I am going to create second segue the first one disappear. Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks in advance. This is updated question.

```
if segue.identifier == "segue" {
    let destVC = segue.destination as! AnotherVC
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! AnotherTableViewCell
    let valueToPass = cell.storeName.text
    destVC.storeName = valueToPass
} else if segue.identifier == "somesegue" {

}
```

Comment: Please share the type of tableview cell either it is dynamic or static.

Comment: how you are doing segue? show code or stroyboard, you can easily add a lot of segues but if you are doing that from one cell how do you want it to work? 4 segues at once?

Comment: I have dynamic tableview @RamkrishnaSharma

Comment: Show your code of doing what you write above

Comment: If you are using the dynamic type then you can connect only one segue at a time via storyboard. But if you are using the static type then you can add multiple segue.

Comment: You can connect multiple Segue from one view controller to other different view controllers. Then With the help of identifier you can perform Segue in DidSelectRow Method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to create multiple segue from storyboard but attach them not to cell but from viewController. Give them names and in  tableView didSelectRow method check for cell indexPath and call self.performSegueWithIdentifier("right identifier") and your viewController will make transition

Answer (score 1):

You must link the ViewController1 to ViewController2 instead of a control in ViewController1 to ViewController2. See image below:

[Segue Linking of ViewControllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quMa1.png)